# NotificationListenerService иногда перестает работать

Tags: java, android, android-notification

Не знаю при каких условиях, но иногда перестает работать мой сервис по отлову уведомлений..
Вот код:

```
public class NotificationsService extends NotificationListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "onNotificationPosted call");
        if (sbn != null) {
            final String packageName = sbn.getPackageName();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(packageName)) {
                if (sbn.getNotification() != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(sbn.getNotification().tickerText)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);
                    intent.putExtra("data", sbn);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "sendBroadcast: " + Constants.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
            Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "onNotificationPosted " + packageName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        // Nothing to do
    }
}
```

Можете что нибудь подсказать?

Answer (score 3):

любой сервис может быт закрыт осью. Даже самый липучий прилипучий =) Допустим, системе не хватает памяти и она вычищает ваш вервис из памяти - вот он и перестает рабоатть. Есть способы которые повышают живучисть сервисов, но ни один из способов не гарантирует, что система не сможет убить ваш сервис.
Можете почитать здесь:
http://programador.ru/sticky-service/

Comment: Сервис, наследник от NotificationListenerService - вроде как запускает сама система же?

Comment: за это не скажу. Могу сказать только что его та же система и убивает. Я бы попробовал его пересоздавать, когда его убивают